# Nested if failure - Pseudo code sample

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

For the past days I've been trying to understand why a script I have is failing, and execution all refers, in the error, to this part of the code (pseudo-code for this post):

```
if [ -z "${removed-unset}" ]; then
    ABC
    else
        if [ "$(date +%u)" == 4 ];  then
            if test `find "ABC" -cmin +2880` then
                if [ ! -f /tmp/ABC ]; then
                    CODE HERE
                        if [[ -s ABC ]]; then
                            CODE HERE
                                if [ -z "${ABC-unset}" ]; then
                                     CODE HERE
                                else
                                     CODE HERE
                                fi
                         else
                             rm ABC
                         fi
                 else
                     CODE HERE
                 fi
             else
                 CODE HERE
             fi
    else
        CODE HERE
    fi
fi
```

I was wondering if I could have some pointers as to what it is I'm doing wrong here. I apologize for the lack of actual code and the syntax.

Comment: [ShellCheck](http://shellcheck.net) helpfully points out that you need a semicolon before `then` in ``if test `find "ABC" -cmin +2880` then``

Comment: That was exactly it! THANK YOU! Can you please submit that as an answer for me to accept it? ShellCheck is going right into the favorites! :)

Comment: I did, but you can also consider deleting the question under the "a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error" clause

Comment: BTW, see the docs about building a [mcve] -- a question about code should have the *shortest possible code* someone else can run to see the same problem themselves. "Someone else can run" means it should actually work (enough to showcase the problem being asked about), ie. that your `CODE HERE`s should be replaced with something else (`echo`s?), and "shortest possible" means that if you don't need to nest your `if`s five deep to show the problem, you shouldn't. We're not asking for your *actual code*, but we *are* asking for code that produces your *actual problem* when actually run.

Comment: This code *does* show the problem when run exactly as posted (``line 21: syntax error near unexpected token `else'``)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ShellCheck](http://shellcheck.net) points out that you're missing a semicolon:

```
if test `find "ABC" -cmin +2880` then
                                 ^-- SC1010: Use semicolon or linefeed before 'then' 
                                             (or quote to make it literal).
```

Just insert it as suggested:

```
if test `find "ABC" -cmin +2880`; then
```

This is required because `then` is only special at the start of a command.

Comment: This solves the OP's immediate issue, but is not particularly correct without quotes -- if more than one file is found, or something is found that contains spaces in its name, the behavior of `test` is hard to predict here.